# Login issue in Laravel 5.3

Tags: laravel

while login or fetching data from database given below error.

> Query Exception in Connection.php line 770: could not find
>   driver

-> I have tried all solutions such as .env , database.php and auth.php file database declaration.

[See screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qzVx7.png)

Answer (score 1):

If you are running a local server make sure to have

> extension=pdo_mysql.so

enabled in the php.ini, to check this you can print our phpinfo() inside a controller.

Answer (score 0):

Please check you have done the following steps in your project

1. Create database and required tables
2. Add the database details in .env

> ```
> DB_HOST=localhost
> DB_DATABASE=Your_Database_Name
> DB_USERNAME=Your_Database_Username
> DB_PASSWORD=Your_Database_Password
> ```

3. Try to register user details
4. Try to login